# How do I disable csrf protection for springfox Swagger UI without Spring Security or Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

We have a REST API using Spring MVC that doesn't use Spring Security or Spring Boot. The rest API url is `{domain}/product/rest/v1/{controller}`. We also have a regular web GUI using Struts2 that is just at {domain}/product/{action}.

We're currently researching autogenerating API documentation using Springfox-swagger and springfox-swagger-ui. It was fairly easy to get Swagger to work using minimal configuration, but the problem is that Springfox by default tries to do a CRSF token request, which we don't use in the rest API. I've googled how to disable this, but every article I can find talks about how to disable it using the Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurationManager. We don't use Spring Security and would rather not have to add it.

Is there a way to disable the Springfox Swaggger UI CSRF token check without using Spring Security or Spring Boot?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using spring-security? Please check dependency tree to confirm that, maybe some of your dependency uses it.

Comment: @RMachnik No, we don't use it. Spring-Security is not found anywhere in the dependency list as managed by Ivy. We have aop, beans, context, context-support, core, expression, jcl, oxm, plugin-core, plugin-metadata, test, web and webmvc, all version 5.06 (plugin is 1.2.0). Springfox is core, schema, spi, spring-web, swagger-common, swagger-ui, swagger2, all version 2.9.2.

Answer (score -2):

For disable the csrf () you need to add spring security in your project follows these link how to disable csrf() in spring.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: As I said, I was hoping for a way that doesn't involve adding spring-security to our project, as we don't know what the consequences of that would be on other aspects like our authentication and authorization. Also, this is Springfox doing this, so I was hoping for a way to disable it on the springfox side.

Comment: For authentication you are using this interface  "org.springframework.security.authentication" Or what??.If you are already using this interface then you should call WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Class for disable the csrf().

Comment: I'm not using anything out of the box from Spring, I'm using a custom written module (we predate Spring Security with our app) that's essentially a filter checking whether your current session contains an object that's added to your session when you log in. All it uses is a cookie with the ID of your current session (yes, I know it's not stateless, but we decided using something like an API key is out of scope).